# Can we request for two media type in one request in rest - like xml and json

Tags: rest, jersey

Can any one any idea about this, please let me know this is the interview question and I am unable to find ans.thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a RESTful service return both JSON and XML for the same resource, depending on the request header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362607/can-a-restful-service-return-both-json-and-xml-for-the-same-resource-depending)

Comment: Thanks its same ..